The photoURL of firebase authentication is not updating
I tried to upload my image in imgbb through api and to update the photUrl of the firebase authentication with the link that I get in return in React JS. Here's my code:
const { signUp, googleLogin } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(true);
  const handleShowPassword = () => {
    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
  };
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState("");
  const [img, setImg] = useState();

  const handleImageUpload = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("key", "MY_API_KEY");
      formData.append("image", img);

      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload",
        formData
      );

      if (response.data.success) {
        console.log(response.data.data.url);
        setImageURL(response.data.data.url);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Image upload failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error.message);
    }
  };
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setImg(file);
  };
  const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    const email = form.get("email");
    const name = form.get("name");
    const password = form.get("password");
    const retypePassword = form.get("retype-password");
    const passwordRegex =
      /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$/;
    if (!passwordRegex.test(password)) {
      toast.error(
        "Password must contain at least 6 characters with at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one digit, and one special character."
      );
      return;
    }
    if (password !== retypePassword) {
      toast.error(
        "You have to type the same password in both fields...kindly check..."
      );
      return;
    }
    try {
      await handleImageUpload();
      signUp(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          toast.success("Signed up successfully");
          updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
            displayName: name,
            photoURL: imageURL,
          })
            .then(() => {
              console.log("Profile updated successfully");
              navigate("/");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error updating profile:", error.message);
              toast.error("Error updating profile: " + error.message);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error signing up:", error.message);
          toast.error(error.message);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error.message);
      toast.error("Error uploading image: " + error.message);
    }
  };


But always I get the name updated perfectly but the photourl as null.
I tried to console log imageUrl and got the link of the image. But then why the updateProfile is not updating it?
I thought my updateProfile function is not working...but then how the name gets updated?
